# How to install packages using pip in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, pip

I have created a job in jenkins and trying to build my project.

My shell command:

```
#!/bin/bash
source env/bin/activate
cd PetInstantApi
pip install -r requirements.txt
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py test
```

My console output says it's failed when installing packages in requirements file.

```
  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8.dist-info'
```

i have tried using

```
sudo     pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `sudo` prompts for a password. Basically, you have two options of solving that:

1. running Jenkins as root, which is obviously not what you'd like to do, or
2. allowing the user that Jenkins runs under to execute `pip` specifically without a password. Add the following line to the end of `/etc/sudoers` file (make sure to use `sudo visudo` for editing that):

   `jenkins_user   ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/pip`